# Dynamic Bayesian network notation

Tags: notation, state-space-models

I am reading Murphy's thesis on Dynamic Bayesian networks [[**pdf download**]](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Thesis/thesis.pdf). On page 14 (27 of the pdf) the variables within a DBNs are defined by a collection of nodes "$Z_t = (U_t , X_t , Y_t )$ to represent the input, hidden and output variables of a state-space model." What are *input* nodes please. How do they differ from *observed* nodes?

Comment: Could be wrong, but that strikes me as a typo. In Bayesian Networks, $U_t$ usually represents an unobserved input to the network, and $X_t$ is usually an observed input. The $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are all observed. This, at least, is the usage in, say, Pearl's work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AdrianKeister. I don't think it is a typo as similar notation is used in [learning Dynamic Bayesian networks by ghahramani -- [top of page 8 in **pdf download**](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/vietri.pdf). At the top of page 8 in *"Often, the observations can be divided into a set of input (or predictor) variables and output (or response) variables.".

Comment: ... I suppose it could be that we think of the inputs as factor which *cause* a latent state (possibly an action?) and the output s as the manifest / indicator variables of the latent. Perhaps?

Comment: Maybe you're right. I may have been thinking of controllable inputs, $X_t$, versus non-controllable inputs $U_t.$ You might have to specify explicitly any unobserved nodes. Input nodes are nodes that have no parent in the network (no arrows going into them), but do have children (arrows going out of them). Unobserved nodes are nodes representing variables for which you do not have data.

Comment: From a causal Bayesian network standpoint, inputs are definitely viewed as causal, and outputs are definitely viewed as effects.

Comment: Thanks. I think the key may your comment *"Input nodes are nodes that have no parent in the network "*